LXC container not starting in 24.04
I am having a big issue starting an LXC container no matter what distro it is. I get these error messages:

lxc-start: mycontainer: ../src/lxc/lxccontainer.c:
wait_on_daemonized_start: 878 Received container state "ABORTING"
instead of "RUNNING"
lxc-start: mycontainer: ../src/lxc/tools/lxc_start.c: main: 306 The
container failed to start
lxc-start: mycontainer: ../src/lxc/tools/lxc_start.c: main: 309 To
get more details, run the container in foreground mode
lxc-start: mycontainer: ../src/lxc/tools/lxc_start.c: main: 311
Additional information can be obtained by setting the --logfile and
--logpriority options
lxc-start: mycontainer: ../src/lxc/lxccontainer.c:
wait_on_daemonized_start: 878 Received container state "ABORTING"
instead of "RUNNING"
lxc-start: mycontainer: ../src/lxc/tools/lxc_start.c: main: 306 The
container failed to start
lxc-start: mycontainer: ../src/lxc/tools/lxc_start.c: main: 309 To
get more details, run the container in foreground mode
lxc-start: mycontainer: ../src/lxc/tools/lxc_start.c: main: 311
Additional information can be obtained by setting the --logfile and
--logpriority options

And this is the logfile output:

lxc-start mycontainer 20240813222057.438 ERROR    conf -
../src/lxc/conf.c:turn_into_dependent_mounts:3951 - No such file or
directory - Failed to recursively turn old root mount tree into
dependent mount. Continuing...
lxc-start mycontainer 20240813222057.480 ERROR    cgfsng -
../src/lxc/cgroups/cgfsng.c:cg_legacy_set_data:3098 - No such file or
directory - Failed to setup limits for the "devices" controller. The
controller seems to be unused by "cgfsng" cgroup driver or not
enabled on the cgroup hierarchy
lxc-start mycontainer 20240813222057.480 ERROR    cgfsng -
../src/lxc/cgroups/cgfsng.c:cgfsng_setup_limits_legacy:3165 - No such
file or directory - Failed to set "devices.deny" to "a"
lxc-start mycontainer 20240813222057.480 ERROR    start -
../src/lxc/start.c:lxc_spawn:1893 - Failed to setup legacy device
cgroup controller limits
lxc-start mycontainer 20240813222057.481 ERROR    lxccontainer -
../src/lxc/lxccontainer.c:wait_on_daemonized_start:878 - Received
container state "ABORTING" instead of "RUNNING"
lxc-start mycontainer 20240813222057.481 ERROR    lxc_start -
../src/lxc/tools/lxc_start.c:main:306 - The container failed to start
lxc-start mycontainer 20240813222057.481 ERROR    lxc_start -
../src/lxc/tools/lxc_start.c:main:309 - To get more details, run the
container in foreground mode
lxc-start mycontainer 20240813222057.481 ERROR    lxc_start -
../src/lxc/tools/lxc_start.c:main:311 - Additional information can be
obtained by setting the --logfile and --logpriority options
lxc-start mycontainer 20240813222057.481 ERROR    start -
../src/lxc/start.c:__lxc_start:2107 - Failed to spawn container
"mycontainer"

I have tried different distros, updated LXC, rebooted my PC and made sure that the container was created successfully. Any help would be very much appreciated.
UPDATE:
This is the error message after adding the missing folders:

lxc-start: mycontainer: ../src/lxc/lxccontainer.c: wait_on_daemonized_start: 878 Received container state "ABORTING" instead of "RUNNING"

lxc-start: mycontainer: ../src/lxc/tools/lxc_start.c: main: 306 The container failed to start

lxc-start: mycontainer: ../src/lxc/tools/lxc_start.c: main: 309 To get more details, run the container in foreground mode

lxc-start: mycontainer: ../src/lxc/tools/lxc_start.c: main: 311 Additional information can be obtained by setting the --logfile and --logpriority options


This is the logfile after creating the missing folders:

lxc-start mycontainer 20240814140044.378 ERROR    conf - ../src/lxc/conf.c:turn_into_dependent_mounts:3951 - No such file or directory - Failed to recursively turn old root mount tree into dependent mount. Continuing...

lxc-start mycontainer 20240814140044.423 ERROR    cgfsng - ../src/lxc/cgroups/cgfsng.c:cg_legacy_set_data:3098 - No such file or directory - Failed to setup limits for the "devices" controller. The controller seems to be unused by "cgfsng" cgroup driver or not enabled on the cgroup hierarchy

lxc-start mycontainer 20240814140044.423 ERROR    cgfsng - ../src/lxc/cgroups/cgfsng.c:cgfsng_setup_limits_legacy:3165 - No such file or directory - Failed to set "devices.deny" to "a"

lxc-start mycontainer 20240814140044.423 ERROR    start - ../src/lxc/start.c:lxc_spawn:1893 - Failed to setup legacy device cgroup controller limits

lxc-start mycontainer 20240814140044.423 ERROR    lxccontainer - ../src/lxc/lxccontainer.c:wait_on_daemonized_start:878 - Received container state "ABORTING" instead of "RUNNING"

lxc-start mycontainer 20240814140044.423 ERROR    lxc_start - ../src/lxc/tools/lxc_start.c:main:306 - The container failed to start

lxc-start mycontainer 20240814140044.423 ERROR    lxc_start - ../src/lxc/tools/lxc_start.c:main:309 - To get more details, run the container in foreground mode

lxc-start mycontainer 20240814140044.423 ERROR    lxc_start - ../src/lxc/tools/lxc_start.c:main:311 - Additional information can be obtained by setting the --logfile and --logpriority options

lxc-start mycontainer 20240814140044.423 ERROR    start - ../src/lxc/start.c:__lxc_start:2107 - Failed to spawn container "mycontainer"


I am stumped to say the least. It still says that the folders are not there though they show up in the tree view for the /src folder.

Your log clearly shows several "No such file or directory" errors. Fix those first.

Please edit your question to add new information or clarifications, properly formatted. Unformatted garbage in a comment is not readable and does not tell us anything that might help you.
